# MVC 3 relative path to ./bin/

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, path

I'm building an MVC 3 project which requires a reference, by path, in the controller to an assembly sitting in the `\bin\` folder of the project.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to constructing a relative path to the `\bin\` folder?

Running the project in debug mode in VS 2010 causes the current directory to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0`, so using `.\bin\` looks for a `bin` folder in that path.

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use current appdomain to get this information.

```
// 1) get current directory for this loaded assembly
// 2) combine path to get \bin folder 
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
```

Answer (score 13):

Since you're in a Controller you have access to an instance of [HttpServerUtilityBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutilitybase.aspx), which exposes a [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutilitybase.mappath.aspx) method:

```
var binDirectoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/bin");
```

This has the added benefit of being trivially unit testable, since the MapPath method is virtual and can be mocked.